# How to declare text with a line

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming and decided to take VB.net up as my first language, I'm quite new and I'm currently trying to write a sorting program. I'm trying to load in a file, search the file for a specific value within a line, and then declare that value.

Here's my code:

```
Using currentfilereader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
        line = currentfilereader.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            If line.Contains("0" Or "1" Or "2" Or "3" Or "4" Or "5" Or "6" Or "8" Or "9" Or "10") Then
            [help]
            End If
            list.Add(line)
            Console.WriteLine(line)
            line = currentfilereader.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using
```

So what I'm asking is how do I declare the searched for number, and is there any easy way to search for numbers rather than list all of them?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHJdP.jpg

Comment: that is not how `Contains()` works.  It does not take an expression.  See [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dy85x1sa(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Perhaps the list.Find function is better? I don't know how to use that though

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far?

Comment: So you want to create a variable for each ocurrence?

Comment: I'm not sure, it would be inefficient, but I cant use an array as there isn't a specific of number lines to read from or can I?

Comment: For Douglas Barbin, I create a file with a name and a value next to it, I want to be able to sort the list of names by the values next to them. I haven't tried anything as such as I have no idea where to begin although I know what I want to do.

Comment: What does your input file look like?  Is the file really RTF (Rich Text Format)?  If so, you may have more issues, since a line in the file (as in what `ReadLine` is looking for) is not necessarily going to be equivalent to a line you would see on the screen in Word (which would be `\line` in RTF).  The may also be RTF control codes containing numbers in the file (e.g. `\f0`).

Comment: Opened it up in notepad, each line is seperate, so "Name:  | Score: 9" and
"Name: Jon | Score: 0" are on different lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression to check for a match and extract the score values would be one option.  Using `File.ReadLines` (or `File.ReadAllLines` pre .NET 4.0) will simplify the IO.  You can also use LINQ to query for the matching lines and sort them:

```
Dim sortedScores =
    From line in File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Let match = Regex.Match(line, "Score: (\d+)")
    Where match.Success
    Order By CInt(match.Groups(1).Value) Descending
    Select line
For Each line In sortedScores
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

You can remove the `Descending` is you want lowest to highest.

If you want to extract the score values, you could modify the query slightly:

```
Dim justTheScores =
    From line in File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Let match = Regex.Match(line, "Score: (\d+)")
    Where match.Success
    Select CInt(match.Groups(1).Value)
```

`justTheScores` will be an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` containing just the scores.

More useful may be to extract the name and score:

```
Dim results =
    From line in File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Let match = Regex.Match(line, "Name: (.*) \| Score: (\d+)")
    Where match.Success
    Select Name = match.Groups(1).Value, Score = CInt(match.Groups(2).Value)
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types with `Name` and `Score` properties.

Comment: One error I face is this "Range variable 'line' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression."

Comment: @Jonathanwashere You probably have a `line` variable declared somewhere else in your code.  You can change `line` in the above code to whatever you want (change all occurrences).

Comment: Well initially I want them to be displayed in the order they appear in the file, but I want the option to sort them •Sort results alphabetically, • highest to lowest score
However highest to lowest is most important at the moment. I can display the results but its the sorting that I am stuck on. Unsure if you've seen the other I've posted but this may help? http://i.imgur.com/mDppEib.jpg http://pastebin.com/e3dn0nSR

Comment: It's only only declared once

Comment: @Jonathanwashere `line` must not be declared anywhere in your code to use the examples as-is.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your patience, I've done so, but now get the following error: Name 'Regex' is either not declared or not in the current scope

Comment: @Jonathanwashere You will need `Using System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of the file.

Comment: Just did so, and it works, you're such a legend! Been stuck on this for ages, if I could I'd kiss you, I joke but the sentiment is there. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that learning RegEx is not learning programming - it is learning how to use RegEx which has little to do with programming. While RegEx is a fine tool to have in your skill set it is one with limited application. Come back to it later...

Answer (score 0):

```
Using currentfilereader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Do
        line = currentfilereader.ReadLine
        If IsNumeric(line) AndAlso CInt(line) >= 1 AndAlso CInt(line)<= 10 Then
            list.Add(line)
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    Loop Until currentfilereader.EndOfStream
End Using
```

Since it seems all you are wanting is values 0 - 10, you can convert line to an integer and check if it is within that range.

AndAlso is a short-circuited comparison, meaning that as soon as one of your values is False, it'll stop comparing and carry on.

Also, you should make sure your readers end when they find EndOfStream, rather than when your line is Nothing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm lacking in capacity or otherwise but I don't get what you've done? The line contains text too, sorry if I'm not very helpful but I've included a link to a photo if that helps in my main post. But the help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to save every number of the file in a array:

```
  Dim fileReader As StreamReader
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("F:\\test.txt")

    Dim numeros As New List(Of String)

    Dim stringReader As String
    stringReader = Convert.ToChar(fileReader.Read)

    Do While (fileReader.Peek() >= 0)
        stringReader = Convert.ToChar(fileReader.Read)

        If stringReader Like "#" Then
            numeros.Add(stringReader)
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: I really dont think I'm saying the correct things, I wish for the console to display the lines within the file and then option to sort them and redisplay them in the console. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/e3dn0nSR

Answer (score 0):

This can be done much faster

```
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
For Each line as String in lines

    ' here I am not sure what you asking but you can do these to identify line
    ' Regex.Match("[0-9]+")
    ' line.contains...
    ' line.IndexOf...

    ' Do whatever you need with the line here

Next
```