# Sort a file alphabetically

Tags: vb.net

I was helped previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190942/how-to-declare-text-with-a-line) however I require more assistance. The code works as intended but I need some more function out of it.

My objective is to sort a list of names with there "scores" alphabetically and by highest to lowest. 'Mark' helped me sort the scores but I now wish for the results to be sorted alphabetically

The code I was given:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
        Dim sortedScores =
    From line In File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Let match = regex.Match(line, "Sore: (\d+)")
    Where match.Success
    Order By CInt(match.Groups(1).Value) Descending
    Select line
        For Each line In sortedScores
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Next
```

And it works magically.

The file looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/Wkqk2hDq)

I modified the code I was given to sort alphabetically but the program just goes blank and nothing happens.

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
        Dim sortedScores =
    From line In File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
    Let match = regex.Match(line, "Name: (\d+)")
    Where match.Success
    Order By CStr(match.Groups(1).Value) Descending
    Select line
        For Each line In sortedScores
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Next
```

Any help on managing to fix this would be brilliant and greatly appreciated!

If I've missed anything let me know, thank you!

EDIT:

The original code working for sorting in alphabetical order:
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\w+")
            Dim sortedNames =
        From line In File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
        Let match = regex.Match(line, "Name: (\w+)")
        Where match.Success
        Order By CStr(match.Groups(1).Value) Ascending
        Select line
            For Each line In sortedNames
                Console.WriteLine(line)
            Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different approach: if you want a String (a name) associated with a value (the score, as an Integer), I think the best fitting object would be a Dictionary:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) 'Key: Name, Value: Score
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")
For Each line As String In lines
    Dim lineParts() As String = line.Split("¦")
    Dim name As String = lineParts(0).Replace("Name : ","")
    Dim score As String = lineParts(1).Replace("Score : ","")
    dict.Add(name, Integer.Parse(score))
Next
```

Now the name and the score are linked, and you can sort them by score:

```
Dim pairList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = (From entry In dict Order By entry.Value Ascending Select entry).ToList()

For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In pairList 
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Score: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)
Next
```

...or by name:

```
Dim sortedNames = dict.Keys.ToList().Sort()
For Each name As String In sortedNames
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Score: {1}", name, dict(name))
Next
```

Comment: Hmm, looks good however, I get an odd error? 'Sort' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer).KeyCollection'.
I use Visual studio as an IDE so I'm assuming there's a line I need somewhere?

Comment: I have just edited some details. Anyway, I have no access to your rtf file so I can not run the code.

Comment: Hmm I cannot seem to get it to work, the I get this error when I try each way of sorting: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.ReadLinesIterator' to type 'System.String[]' error seems to be here: Dim lines() As String = File.ReadLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf") If this is unfixable, is the method I was originally using able to be modified to work to sort by name?

Comment: True. Use this instead `File.ReadAllLines("S:\class" & CName & ".rtf")`. I was testing it without the file, and made some edits. It works for me, let me know if you still have troubles making it work.

Comment: Sorry grabbed something to eat, I'm unsure of where to use File.ReadAllLines, doesn't the code already do this?

Comment: Now yes, it does :) (I edited the post after your remark). I'll be off for a while, hope the code works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not, I get this instead: Index was outside the bounds of the array. So close! I don't imagine i'll be back till tomorrow so thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Managed to alter the code I was originally given so that it works, but thank you anyways!