# Load multiple results using RegEx and sort them

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio, sorting

I require some help, if you've seen my other questions it's the same program.

My code uses regular expression to search up specific strings and grab the value next to it. My program is a maths quiz, and can write to a file and read to a file and sort. The next and final thing I want it to do is to be able to sort the results by an average persons score. So the program needs to store only 3 results and take an average of that.

I have no idea if RegEx is the correct or most efficient or simplest method to do what I want to do but it has worked solidly so far. Here's what I've done:

```
filename = "N:\Year 10\Computing\A453 Controlled Assessment\class" & Students.CName & ".rtf" 'stores filename with the value of "Students.CName" to determine the file

    currentfilewriter = New StreamWriter(filename, FileMode.Append) 'links file name to opened channel, allows rewriting to file

    currentfilewriter.WriteLine("First name: " & Students.FName & " | Last name: " & Students.LName & " | Score: " & score & " | Attempt: " & attempt)
    'writes users score, first name and last name to file
    currentfilewriter.WriteLine()
    'enters blank score in file
    Console.Clear() 'clears console

    currentfilewriter.Close()
    'closes the file and saves it

    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
    Dim attempts =
From line In File.ReadLines("N:\Year 10\Computing\A453 Controlled Assessment\class" & Students.CName & ".rtf")
Let match = Regex.Match(line, "Attempt: (\d+)")
Where match.Success
    attempt = attempt - 1
    If attempt = 0 Then

    End If
```

What I essentially want this to do is where it says

```
If attempt = 0 Then
    End If
```

I want it to remove the whole line

The only problem is I have no idea how to actually load 3 results at once and how to sort them nor how to create and show an average for each individual pupil although I don't imagine it's too difficult although I could be wrong.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Extra information:

I'm using VB.net (visual studio)

[How to declare text with a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190942/how-to-declare-text-with-a-line)

[Sort a file alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252412/sort-a-file-alphabetically)

File:

- First name: Jonathan | Last name: 7ifleet | Score: 9
- First name: Jonathan | Last name: 3ifleet | Score: 9
- First name: Jonathan | Last name: 5ifleet | Score: 9
- First name: Jonathan | Last name:  | Score: 4
- First name: Jonathan | Last name: Sifleet | Score: 2
- First name: Michael | Last name: Sifleet1 | Score: 0
- First name: Jonathan | Last name: Sifleet 4| Score: 9
- First name: Jonathan | Last name: Sifleet2 | Score: 4
- (an rtf) ignore the bullet points

Comment: Is it possible to get this data in a not-RTF format?

Comment: Of course, I only use it as docx is too complex and somehow though it was a better choice compared to txt